# how to solve 500 Internal Server Error in joomla?

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

i use com_google_map_vision in my site.when i click on view map then following error display:-

500 Internal Server Error

## Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or
misconfiguration and was unable to complete
your request.

Please contact the server administrator,
 webmaster@openxcelltechnolabs.info and inform them of the time the error occurred,
and anything you might have done that may have
caused the error.

More information about this error may be available
in the server error log.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found
error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

how to solve this error 
hope someone help me

Answer (score 9):

In general the first step when dealing with this sort of error would be to turn on error reporting by putting the following at the beginning of your index.php:

```
ini_set('display_errors','On'); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Doing so might give you some php specific error message with which you will find it easier to troubleshoot the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Error 500 generally occurs when the (web) server is not configured correctly. Many times it means that there is problem with your `.htaccess` file. Please check if you need to do any changes to .htaccess file things to work correctly.

Answer (score 2):

According to Abhijeet Pathak, probably it is related with .htaccess file, specially with the Rewrite module

Check out the "Rewrite /" parameter

Answer (score 0):

That's a long shot, but I recently had a similar issue with Community Builder extension. It turned out it was running out of memory, because it was not able to use all available memory. Adding the following line to .htaccess solved my problem:

```
RLimitMEM MAX MAX
```

I added it right at the beginning of the file. It supposedly allows a php script to use more of the memory assigned in php.ini...

Comment: You set allowed memory for request to be maximum resource limit http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#rlimitmem. This is bad! If 1 request hangs up because of w/e reason, the server will not be usable at all. You should have modified `memory_limit` in `php.ini` to 32MB-64MB depending on your requirements.

Comment: I don't care if it's good or bad, I care about the results. I have 128MB in php.ini and it did not help. RlimitMEM did help, though.

Comment: Well if it helped, you might want to consider giving @silvo a credit for his help. Give him +1 for his effort and accept his answer as correct one!

Answer (score 0):

Try recursively setting the permissions on components/com_google_map_vision and administrator/components/com_google_map_vision to 755 for folders and 644 for files.

This type of error is usually due to a permissions issue in Joomla.

Answer (score 0):

Please change the file permission as follows.

- All folders to 755
- All files to 644

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused by the permissions of files and folders.
The files should be chmod 644 and folders 755

Executing these instructions into the shell solves the problem

```
sudo find. -type f-print0 | xargs -0 chmod 0664

sudo find. -type d-print0 | xargs -0 chmod 0775
```

PD: enter the root of joomla before executing commands

Answer (score 0):

Its because of IP address,you used foreign or totally different,therefore your host company denied permission,you should firstl identify your Ip then call them to add this Ip to their secure ip's.

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading Joomla! on local development machine, remember to check if you have enabled `mod_rewrite`.Because this causes Internal Server Error 500. Most of the time it happens

1. Because it was never enabled in the first palce
2. A wamp/lamp update may have reset your `.conf` file
3. The new version of `apache` may use a different file name or a directory altogether for the `.conf` file.

Uncomment the row in `httpd.conf` or a file named something similar (whatever  your wamp/lamp stack names it, eg. mine is `httpd_uwamp.conf` so yours may vary).

And you should be good to go, **after restarting** the server.

Answer (score -2):

try this please.. All you have to do is put this line of code on your .htaccess file:

```
AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
```